# OAuth vulnerability

Tags: bug, security, oauth2

I signed up for SO (years ago) using my Yahoo account. Today I accidentally signed-in using Facebook and was surprised that I was logged into my existing SO account (the same one created from my Yahoo account). Although the email address I use on Facebook is my Yahoo address, I still don't think this should happen. It seems that the logic being employed is:

> if a user signs in with an OAuth provider and we have an account with the same email address, log them into this account

Doesn't this create the following vulnerability

- Alice registers for SO with her email address and a password
- Alice also has signed up to Facebook with this email address
- Eve gains access to Alice's Facebook account
- Eve can now use her illicit access to Alice's Facebook account to also access her SO account

I think what should happen in the case above, is that a new account is created when Eve logs into SO with Alice's Facebook account.

Comment: I'm just gonna blame Alice.

Comment: `i am a stoopid idoit.. hahahahha hacked!` - Alice's Facebook, probably

Comment: Perhaps more interestingly, what will the system do if Eve signs in using a custom OpenID / OAuth provider that claims her e-mail address matches that of Alice?

Comment: Security problems like this should really be communicated to SE in private instead of posting it on Meta so everyone can abuse it.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen if you're going to do identity matching based on email addresses - which is what SO are doing - you need to have a very high level of confidence in the email verification processes of the OAuth providers

Comment: @Stijn in this particular case you need to gain access to another SO user's Google/Twitter account in order to take advantage of this exploit, so it's not something that can readily be exploited

Comment: @Dónal and what if said user does not have a Google/Twitter account? Then you might be able to sign up and execute the exploit anyway.

Comment: @Stijn You'd have to have control of someone's email account in order to do that.

Comment: Isn't that up to the provider though @Bill? If they don't require email confirmation, then it would be plausible. I was curious about facebook, so I just tried with an older account and they do require email confirmation.

Comment: @CarrieKendall Yes, it is up to the provider, but I know in this case that Google/Twitter/Facebook all require email confirmation. I don't know what all providers SE recognizes, but I'd guess email confirmation would be common among them.

Comment: After some investigating, it seems that the other non-email based providers don't link to an email automatically (ie you have to do that with an ongoing session). So, no vulnerability unless, as Bill stated, they have access to your email.

Comment: Interestingly enough though, LiveJournal does not require email verification. Just putting that out there since it seems that depending on implementation, that could be exploited elsewhere.

Comment: @CarrieKendall even if the provider has a rock solid email verification there _is_ still a vulnerability because gaining control of a verified Facebook/Google/Twitter account also gives you access to a stackoverflow account that uses the same email address

Answer (score 7):

I think this is working as intended. This behaviour should only exist for trusted identity providers who validate emails. If anybody sees this behavior in a different/exploitable context, please say so.

> You don't even have to bother with associating the accounts if you are using an existing "trusted“ provider like Gmail, Yahoo, etc. -just use the same email when registering, and the association will be automatic. –  Shog9♦ [Jul 7 '12 at 14:45](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138994/how-can-i-log-in-to-my-stack-exchange-account-if-my-current-account-provider-is#comment391406_138997)

> is the automagic association only for the "top" providers (SE, Google, Yahoo & Facebook right now), or all the providers that have an icon in the login page (~9 more)? –  Mat [Jul 7 '12 at 14:55](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138994/how-can-i-log-in-to-my-stack-exchange-account-if-my-current-account-provider-is#comment391409_138997)

> only the top verified ones we really trust –  Nick Craver♦ [Jul 7 '12 at 15:03](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138994/how-can-i-log-in-to-my-stack-exchange-account-if-my-current-account-provider-is#comment391415_138997)

Comment: If I remember correctly, Facebook hasn't necessarily verified the email address they return. When I created Facebook OAuth login support for one of my sites, we couldn't trust the address from Facebook. Has this changed recently?

Comment: @JoshuaDwire I'm not sure whether it changed recently, but I tested this today and they require email verification upon the OAuth request from SO.

Comment: @CarrieKendall I tested again today, and it does seem safe to trust the email address. I'm assuming it can't be gotten around by verifying a phone number instead.

Answer (score 1):

I think the logic behind this makes sense, you assume Eve gains access to Alice's Facebook, which usually is Alice's fault, the same can happen to her email account if she is not careful enough,
So in this case I don't see much difference between gaining access to email and Facebook.

Comment: One difference is that you control your application's email verification process, but you don't control the OAuth providers' email verification process